# change iteration variable within for loop

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to print some elements in array.My array is like,

```
prmArray={"[]","int","[]","[]","float","[]","[]","[]","string"}
```

what I'm trying to print is,

```
int[] float[][] string[][][]
```

I've been trying various things and it got messy now..
My code is,

```
 String ps=""; 
 int u=0; 
    for(int y=0;y<prmArray.length;y=u)
        {
            String br_string="";

            if(prmArray[y].equals("[]")){
                int f=y+1; 
                br_string+="[]";
                for(int h=f;h<prmArray.length;h++){
                    u=h;
                    if(prmArray[h]=="[]"){
                        br_string+="[]";
                    }
                    else{
                        u=u-1; 
                        break;
                    }
                }
                ps+=prmArray[u+1]+br_string+" ";
                u=u+2;
            } 

            else{
                ps+=prmArray[y]+" ";
                u=u+1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(ps);
```

please help..

Comment: You could create a Stack.

Comment: If any of the answers below solved your problem you can consider accepting one so that the question gets marked as resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
public static String formatArray(String[] prmArray){
    String result = "";
    String tempResult = "";
    for (String entry: prmArray){
        if(entry.equals("[]")){
            tempResult += entry;
        }else{
            tempResult = entry + tempResult;
            //flip tempResult
            result += tempResult + " ";
            tempResult = "";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack implementation:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Stk {
    public static void main(String...orange)
    {
        String [] prmArray={"[]","int","[]","[]","float","[]","[]","[]","string"};
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        for (String str : prmArray)
        {
            if (str.equals("[]"))
                stack.push(str);
            else
            {
                while(!stack.isEmpty())
                    str+=stack.pop();
                System.out.print(str + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
int[] float[][] string[][][]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have well understood what you are trying to do, you don't need nested loops, you can do it in a single pass, putting in your `br_string` the `"[]"` you've encountered so far.
When you find something else you build a part of your final result (`ps` ) and go on ;-)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] prmArray={"[]","int","[]","[]","float","[]","[]","[]","string"};

    String ps = "";
    String br_string="";

    for (int i = 0 ; i< prmArray.length ; i++) {

        if(prmArray[i].equals("[]")){
            br_string += prmArray[i];
        } else {
            br_string = prmArray[i] + br_string + " ";
            ps += br_string;
            br_string = "";
        }
    }

    System.out.println(ps);

}
```